# sql migration with macro or script

Tags: sql-server, regex, scripting, macros, migration

I have many Oracle objects (views, procs, etc.) that I am migrating to SQL Server in a completely revamped database design.

The approach I am taking is to script out objects one by one from Oracle, manually modifying the code in a text editor (notepad++) and scripting into SQL Server. I want to replace that manual piece with a script/macro that I can amend and enhance as I go. Use of regular expressions is essential. Notepad++ doesn't have the functionality I need.

I feel there must be some kind of gold standard toolset/approach for this sort of activity. Can anyone tell me what it is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering in case this is of any use to anyone:
Scripted all objects manually to separate text files from Oracle.
Used Powershell script to convert files en masse to new folder.
Tested and ran-in new objects manually to SQL Server.